# Officedown - Can't print plots (validate_key error)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm testing the `Officedown`-package, but encounter some issues. From the two examples below, the first one produces a word-file, but with warning. The second one stops due to an error I don't understand.

*Example 1*

````
---
title: "Style text with officedown"
output:
  officedown::rdocx_document: default
---

```{r}
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(ggplot2)
library(flextable)

ft <- fp_text(color = 'red', bold = TRUE)
```

# Test

The **officedown** package is
`r ftext('awesome', ft)`!

```{r}
df <- data.frame(A = 1:3,
           B = 1:3)
mytable <- flextable(df, theme_fun = theme_box)

mytable
```
````

*Warning 1*

[image]

*Example 2*

Just one chunk is added to the previous example. Here I make and print a ggplot, but the same error occurs if the chunk only contains `df` (print the dataframe)

````
```{r plot, fig.cap="a cap"}

p <- ggplot(df, aes(A,B))+geom_point()+theme_bw()

print(p)
```
````

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather silly to find the solution minutes after you turn to stackoverflow because google doesn't provide the solution:

I installed the `cachem`-package. I assume it should have come with the `officedown`-installation, but apparently it didn't.